# Error in powershell: operation requires an interactive window station

Tags: powershell, powershell-v3.0

I am executing below command through autosys(scheduling tool) to stop a service but it is failing with below error. The command works fine when i run the command on <kbd>RUN(WIN+R)</kbd> or cmd after RDPing into the server. Can anyone help me here with a right command?

> Command: C:\windows\System32...powershell Start-Process powershell
>   -Verb runAs E:\ABC\stop_service.ps1
>
> Content of stop_service.ps1 = stop-service -name 'service-abc'
>
> Error: Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error:
>   This operation requires an interactive window station.
>
> At line:1 char:1 + Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
>   E:\ABC\stop_service.ps ... +
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOp erationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Answer (score 0):

**To execute a powershell session :**

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File stop_service.ps1
```

**You can directly run the Stop-Service command as :**

```
Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command {Stop-Service -Name <ServiceName> -Force}
```

**Note:** For better results, please make sure to run the command under Administrator context